# Not understanding why javascript prototype data sometimes included in parsed json with ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I've got some very straight forward ExtJS 5 JavaScript that when I try and output the data to a label using encode, I get a different result then when I log it with console.log.  What I want is what comes out of console.log.  Below is an annotated picture describing my issue as well as a fiddle showing the code.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8bo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note, I have experience with JavaScript but I've never used ExtJS before.

Now, having said that, you're not seeing the same results as the console because the `Ext.JSON.encode()` method internally calls `.hasOwnProperty()` for each property in the object returned by `viewModel.getData()`. You can see this for yourself by stepping in to this method via the debugger.

- For `left` - `.hasOwnProperty()` returns true
- For `from1` - `.hasOwnProperty()` returns false.

Since `from1` returns false, the string returned by `Ext.JSON.encode()` does not include this property.

Now, the question becomes: why does it return false for `from1`? This is because your `viewModel` doesn't include `from1` as a property. It currently looks like this:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        left: 'left'
    }
}
```

You need to add `from1` into your `viewModel`.

Now, I did notice one thing. If I added `from1` and set its value to `TopPanel`, it still did not work as expected. If I chose any other value except `TopPanel` things worked as expected and the string outputted by `Ext.JSON.encode()` included the property . It has something to do with the first `viewModel` configuration that you have declared. It currently looks like this:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        from1: 'TopPanel'
    }
...
```

The two `viewModel` configurations are colliding somehow. But I'd have to dig further into how ExtJS works before I could tell you why that is happening. Hopefully, my answer will nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: good insight and thanks.  what baffles me is that I can see from1:toppanel1 in the prototype and somehow console.log shows it and the encode does not. that feels like not an extjs problem but I'm a newbie on using prototype.

Comment: @PeterKellner Even if you replace `Ext.JSON.encode()` with the built-in `JSON.stringify` method, that still doesn't work

Comment: same result. just updated fiddle here so it can be run with that change:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8c2

Comment: @PeterKellner ExtJS is not the problem. `JSON.stringify` a built-in method also produces the same results. I think it is working as expected. You just need to understand [how `.hasOwnProperty()` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). `console.log` probably does not use `.hasOwnProperty()`, which might be why you're seeing different results (it's implemented natively so I'd have to look at the browser's source code to confirm though). Why don't you just use a simple `for in` loop to output the object as a string instead?

Comment: hmm. not sure what the for in loop would look like.  my properties names are not always the same and the nesting levels vary also.